# Replacing within a specific pattern in the string | Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wish to replace character `'/'` when occurred in a certain pattern (preceded and followed by a character) with `""`.

Example

1. `"a/b b/c"` should be replaced to  `"ab bc"`
2. `"a/b python/Java"` should be replaced to  `"ab python/Java"`

While, I know how to substitute using regex `re.sub("/","","a/b python")`, the problem is, that substitution needs to be done only in specific parts of the string.

Any help here will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/nASBji/1/

Answer (score 2):

This simplifies and expands on [Code Maniac's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9624435/code-maniac) comment:

You can replace a found pattern using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

regex = r"(\b\w)\/(\w\b)" # do not capture the /

test_str = """a/b b/c
a/b python/Java"""

subst = r"\1\2"           # replace with 1st and 2nd capture group
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, flags=re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

As pattern `r"(\b\w)\/(\w\b)"` you define a word boundary + 1 word character followed by `\` followed by 1 more word character followed by a word boundary. You capture it as 1. and 2. group - the `\`
 is not captured.

You replace each match by the captured groups before/after `/`.

Output:

```
ab bc
ab python/Java
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/WI0Wg3/1

Answer (score 1):

What you might do is to first match the pattern with a 1+ characters, `/`, 1+ characters between double quotes. Then because the pattern matches, you could split the string and check if then item has a string length of 3.

If it does, use map and replace the `/` with an empty string and reconstruct the string.

Match the full pattern:

```
"\w+\/\w+(?: \w+\/\w+)*"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDUtqj/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MTOoqH)

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"\"\w+\/\w+(?: \w+\/\w+)*\""
test_str = ("\"a/b b/c\"\n"
    "\"a/b python/Java\"")
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    res = map(lambda s: s.replace("/", "") if len(s) == 3 else s, match.strip("\"").split())
    print('"{0}"'.format(" ".join(res)))
```

Result

```
"ab bc"
"ab python/Java"
```